# Redirect Users if they try and access the application on the wrong server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-manager

I have an MVC application, and my company has their own web servers that we publish to.  Now, this application is on server x.. but I have since published it to a new web server (server y).  If user's try and access the application on server x, I need them to be transferred to server y... or at least give them a message stating to go to the new URL.

Is there a way I can do this within IIS Manager on server x?

Comment: Did you check this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1217858.aspx

Comment: @AshleyMedway they are all Intranet sites/applications.. so the URL is like this: `http://servername/foldername`

Comment: @JCM that worked!  Thanks for the info/link!  If you want to post a quick answer/summary of the link I will mark as accepted to save this question as a reference for others who may experience this.

Comment: Thank you GTown-Coder, but it's ok, the big deal here is solve problems.